# How to split huge data set in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to insert nearly 100 million data in the master table where p_id, 
p_name,cat_id,category_name,brand_id,brand_name are the unique in this table structure.

We have nearly 1000 categories in our db.

Table structure:

```
UNIQUE KEY `product_name` (`product_name`,`product_brand`),
```

As above table are using in website queries.

How to split the data?

Comment: you're inserting from mysql table to another mysql table, right ?

Comment: No No.. from CSV we are inserting phase by phase..

Comment: did you try/read about `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` ?

Comment: I know these .. But data set huge..fetching result will be slower.. SInce we are using the queries in website. So  i need a different approach of splitting the data except partition concept.

Comment: Friends, Reply to above query

Comment: Please consider asking this question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to re-write the question. You don't mention at all what this "splitting" is about. You don't even mention CSV in your question. If there's things / techniques you can't use, that needs to be included as well, with the reason why it can't be used.